# AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'acquire'

Tags: multithreading, locking, python-multithreading

In this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGOBQPFzWKo, around 4:16:00, it's talked about how to implement a lock for threading issues. But as opposed to the video, I get a debug message when trying to acquire the lock.

This is a part of the code I tried out for myself:

```
def increase(lock):
    global database_value
    
    lock.acquire()
    local_copy = database_value
    local_copy += 1
    time.sleep(0.1)
    database_value = local_copy
    lock.release()
```

And this is the debug message:

```
Exception in thread Thread-32:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\miniconda3\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
Exception in thread Thread-33:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\miniconda3\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\miniconda3\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\miniconda3\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_75580\1082204269.py", line 14, in increase
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_75580\1082204269.py", line 14, in increase
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'acquire'
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'acquire'
```

In the Jupyter Notebook, there seems to be raised an exception when I try to run the thread.

What's going wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

I tried to do what the video did, I expected it to work, but there's something not working in the thread apparently.

Comment: The error message is complaining about the `lock` object that is passed in by the caller. What kind of object is passed? Where is the code that calls `increase`?

Comment: I somehow forgot parentheses in my call of a Lock object, it should be Lock(), my call is now:  lock = Lock().

Comment: me too) The answer is in comment)